# Convert a regular expression A that accepts a set of strings to one that accepts all prefixes of the strings that A matches

Tags: regex

Given any regular expression A, is there a way to to transform it to anouther regular expression B, that accepts all the strings and prefixes of strings that A accepts.

for example if /apple/ is the given regular expression, is there a generalized way to convert it to /a|ap|app|appl|apple/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about [formal regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) (i.e. regular expressions that describe [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)), then here's a procedure to convert a regular expression into one that accepts prefixes.

Any regular expression has a [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton); here's the DFA for `/apple/` (with transitions to failure states left out):

[image: DFA for /apple/]

To produce a DFA that matches prefixes of strings accepted by this DFA, convert states to [accepting states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine#Accept_.28or_final.29_states) if they lie along paths that lead to accepting states in the original DFA:

[image: DFA for prefixes of /apple/]

There are [several methods](http://neumannhaus.com/christoph/papers/2005-03-16.DFA_to_RegEx.pdf) for reading a regular expression from a DFA.  If we use the state removal technique, we arrive at the following DFA:

[image: DFA for prefixes of /apple/, after state elimination]

This corresponds to the regular expression `/a|ap|app|appl|apple|/`, plus the empty string (since the empty string is a prefix of any regular expression).

The `apple` example is trivial, but this same technique can be used for more complicated regular expressions.  For example, consider `/(00)*1(00|1)*/`:

[image: DFA for /(00)*1(00|1)*/]

This DFA accepts the string `00100` but doesn't accept `0010101`.  After converting the appropriate states to final states and combining two identical states, we have

[image: Slightly minimized DFA for prefixes of /(00)*1(00|1)*/]

This is equivalent to

[image]

from which we can read the regular expression `/(00)*(0?|1(1|00)*0?)/`, which includes the empty string.

This regular expression rejects `00101` because it causes the original DFA to transition into a failing state, but accepts '0' and '00', because those strings do not cause the original DFA to enter a failure state.

Comment: And the answer to the question is?

Comment: Seems like I can use [link]http://www.brics.dk/automaton/doc/index.html to convert a regexp to dfa, do the appropriate manipulations and convert it back to a regexp

Comment: @VimilSaju: I created the diagrams in [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/)

Answer (score 0):

It clearly can be done, by converting to finite state machine, changing all states to accept states, and converting back, as shown in @JoshRosen 's answer.

Here is a more direct algorithm.
For simplicity, I'll assume the formal definition of
regular expression [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition).  So expressions are built recursively from the empty string, literal characters, and operators concatenation, alternation ('|') and Kleene star ('*').  I'll also include the operator '?', such that `A?` is an abbreviation for `(|A)`.

We want to define a transformation P that takes any regular expression A and outputs a regular expression B=P(A) that accepts exactly the prefixes of what A accepts.
The following simple recursive definition of P will do it:

```
P(empty string) = empty string
P(c) = c?   if c is a literal character
P(A?) = P(A)
P(A*) = (A* P(A))
P(A B) = (P(A) | (A P(B)))
P(A|B) = (P(A) | P(B))
```

The proof of correctness is, of course, by induction on the structure of the regex: observe that it's correct for the empty string and literal characters,
and that, if it's correct for `A` and `B`, then it's correct for `A B`, `A|B`, `A*`, and `A?`.

We can also add the following rule, which isn't strictly necessary
but leads to more efficient output expressions in the common case of literal strings (that is, concatenation of several literal characters):

```
P(a B) = (a P(B))?  when a is a literal character
```

### Example

Consider the regular expression `/abc/`.  Usually we don't specify or care whether the concatenation operator is left or right associative, since the resulting accepted language is the same either way.  But let's work through it both ways.

If we treat concatenation as being left-to-right associative:

```
P(/abc/) = P((a b) c)
         = P(a b) | ((a b) P(c))
         = P(a b) | ((a b) c?)
         = (a P(b))? | ((a b) c?)
         = (a b?)? | ((a b) c?)
         = /(ab?)?|abc?/
```

Or, if we treat concatenation as being right-to-left associative, we get a more efficient (linear size, [doesn't repeat itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) output by simply repeatedly applying the `P(a B) = (a P(B))?` rule:

```
P(/abc/) = P(a (b c))
         = (a P(b c))?
         = (a (b P(c))?)?
         = (a (b c?)?)?
         = /(a(bc?)?)?/
```

Answer (score -4):

Depends on what you mean by *generalized way*.

```
\b(a(p?(p?(l?(e?)))))\b
```

**Edit:** a positive look behind addition would represent a better solution but it depends entirely on the regular expression machine implementation.

Comment: This is incorrect; it matches 'ale', which is not a prefix of 'apple'.

Comment: @JoshRosen - Do you comprehend the meaning of regular expression [look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)?