# Partial Matching of Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

In NFA it is easy to make all previously non-final states accepting to make it match language of all substrings of a given language.

In Java regex engine,
is there a way to find out if a string is a starting substring of a string that matches given regex?

expression regexX ~ "any start of", regexA = any normal regex

resulting expression "regexXregexA" matches all starting substrings of all matches of "regexA":

example:

```
regexA = a*b, matches "ab" and not "a"
  
"regexXa*b", matches "a" because it is a start of "ab" (and "aab")
```

edit:

Since some people still fail to understand, here is a program test for this question:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
       String regex = "a*b";
       System.out.println(
       partialMatch(regex, "aaa");
       );
     }
public boolean partialMatch(String regex, String begining){
//return true if there is a string which matches the regex and    
//startsWith(but not equal) begining, false otherwise 
}
}
```

must result in true.

Comment: Could you please explain what is your question about?

Comment: Are you looking for a [word boundary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324676/what-is-a-word-boundary-in-regexes)?

Comment: No, it's very clearly explains in the text of the question. What is regexX?

Comment: you have asked about **java** with no** java** tag.

Comment: I will be ok if you post an answer in any other language.

Comment: "very clearly" is subjective IMHO. At least one other user didn't understand what your question is about.

Comment: You comment is illogical. I'm pretty sure there are more then 1 person who don't understand even calculus even though its questions are surely clearly explained.

Comment: Here is example to make it completely "unsubjective":
   
   import java.util.regex.*;
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String regex = "a*b";
        System.out.println(
        Pattern.matches(regexX+regex, "aaa")
        );
    }
}

Comment: Find a regexX that will result in "true"

Comment: What do you mean by *"`"a"` matches `"regexXa*b"`"*?

Comment: I won't explain what a regular expression is here. Please read the question: I already posted a clear programming example. Just find some string x to substitute for regexX to make program output "true";

Comment: What is **regexX**? a condition to test if there is the second part? and find your pattern if would be there?

Comment: k-five, I don't understand your comment completely. What is regexX? is the question that I ask in the post. Why do you reask it me in the comments..

Comment: This 'regexX+regex' looks like a string cat. Even with partial matching, you'd have to know which part matched. There is no magic bullet I don't think, to force it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're looking for is called *partial matching*, and it's natively supported by the Java regex API (for the record, other engines which offer this feature include PCRE and boost::regex).

You can tell if an input string matched partially by inspecting the result of the [`Matcher.hitEnd`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#hitEnd()) function, which tells if the match failed because the end of the input string was reached.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a*b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("aaa");
System.out.println("Matches: " + matcher.matches());
System.out.println("Partial match: " + matcher.hitEnd());
```

This outputs:

```
Matches: false
Partial match: true
```

Comment: Thank you, that's actually 1-to-1 mapping of the NFA idea. Could you elaborate about how the matches() implemented? Is the just an underlying NFA and if the input end is hit in a nonfinal state(both not accepting and not declining) the "hitEnd" flag gets up?

Comment: @bedbad I don't know the implementation details, but the idea behind it is like you described: if you end up in a nonfinal state with no more possible transitions (because there's no more input), then `hitEnd` will return `true`.

Comment: @bedbad BTW I recently answered a very similar question for JavaScript [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41580048/3764814), you may be interested as JS doesn't provide that feature out of the box and the workaround is (roughly) to rewrite the pattern to include `$` at every "point" in the regex, which is equivalent to marking all possible NFA states as final if the end of the input was reached.

Comment: Here's your bounty, sir. II couldn't find that, the question is fairly underrated in my opinion.
Is it possible to do in java and C/C++ as well? can you link the source boost:regex where it is implemented?

Comment: Yes, you can use PCRE for C and C++, and boost::regex for C++. Here's the [boost partial match doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/partial_matches.html), and here's the [PCRE2 doc about partial matching](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2partial.html)

Answer (score 3):

> In NFA it is easy to make all previously non-final states accepting to make it match language of all substrings of a given language.

Indeed, it can be accomplished by adding a new final state and an ε-move from each state (final or non-final) to the new final state.

Afaik there is no regex equivalent for this operation.

It is possible that some regex libraries provides a way to verify if a string is a partial match of a regex, I don't know. I don't know Java, I work mainly in PHP and it doesn't provide such a feature. Maybe there are libraries that does it but I never needed one.

For a small, specific regex you can try to build a new regex that matches strings that would partially match the original regex by combining this simple rules:

- `a` -> `a?`
- `ab` -> `ab?`
- `a*` -> `a*`
- `a+` -> `a*`
- `a|b` -> `(a|b)?`
- etc

`a` and `b` above are sub-regexps of the original regex. Use parentheses as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt axiac! Unfortunately I can't use small and/or specific regex: I'm building Parser Generator(this part is for Lexer Generator) (so I have no idea what grammar input will be). I need to know if the string so far matches any regular expression.(because the string that finally matches it fully can be "infinitely" long(or very long)).

Comment: Well, if you are building a lexer you should know better than me how to convert NFAs to regexps and vice-versa.

Comment: Yes, it is a solution: convert all runtime regexs to NFAs, make that operation, convert back and do matching.  I stumbled across this problem completely unexpectedly and felt it should take no more than 3 lines of code. I don't know if there is full implementation for NFAs in java standard packages. I just didn't feel right to do it just for this occasion so I asked here. Bottom line I thought that java regexes should do anything for FAs, that's why I asked.

Comment: I didn't mark up your answer because it's actually incorrect. If you try to infer it ("a and b above are sub-regexps of the original regex"). You can see that in the second rule we divide our regex in 2 those subregexs: a and b. 
Then applying (in order) first rule to a -> a? will lead to a?b? which incorrect because it matches "b", which it should not. So a and b can not be other regexs.(i.e the set of doesn't work). What rules should do is finding all possible suffixes and marking them '?'

Comment: I agree with you regarding my answer. You can notice there is an "etc" as the last item; I didn't work very hard writing it and I know it doesn't help you very much. Especially since you don't have a small, known regex that can be easily converted. The second conversion rule should read: `Ab -> Ab?` where `b` is a character and `A` is a sub-expression. The others should also  be reformulated to be usable. Initially I didn't intend to write an answer but it was too long for a comment.

Comment: My counterexample still holds: Ab -> Ab? ->(A)b?->(a)b?->a?b?
not fit. You need to give a set of rules which will do exactly all suffixes optional and nothing more.