# Dart regex match against a stream

Tags: regex, dart, stream

I'm writing code to parse a text file.
The user of my library can pass a line delimiter as a regex.

The file may be large so I need to stream the contents.

So the question is how do I apply the regex to the stream as it passes through my line matcher.

I will apply a limit so the line delimiter matched by the regex may not be greater than 100 chars otherwise the regex has the potential to match the entire contents of the file.

I can't just buffer the 100 char max as the delimiter may span the buffer.

The only idea I can think of is preparsing the regex into segments and checking for partial matched as I go.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's a thorny issue, and not one which has a simple solution.

Your file is large, so you do not want to load it entirely into memory first. That's reasonable.
You do need to buffer *some* of it, at least everything after the last detected line delimiter, so that you can combine that with the next chunk in order to look for delimiters that may be split between the chunks.

That would be my initial approach: Keep a "prefix" string, which is everything after the last line delimiter, and when you receive a new chunk, concatenate that onto the prefix, and then check for line delimiters in the entire available string. If the prefix is (way) more than 100 chars, you can split the prefix into the part that is definitely not part of the delimiter, which you then put into your `StringBuffer` directly, and the last 99 characters which you combine with the next chunk. I'd benchmark that, because it's not at all obvious that it'll be faster than just concatenating the entire thing, but it might be if you get lines spanning many chunks.

If you allow arbitrary `RegExp`s, then there is no simpler solution.(And even that does not allow a `RegExp` which uses look-ahead or look-behind to check characters outside of the 100-char match, perhaps even in earlier or later chunks, you really need the entire file in memory as a string for that kind of shenanigans to work).

Now, if that's too inefficient, perhaps because some lines are large, or some chunks are small, and you are doing a lot of copying to do the concatenation, then I'd move away from using `RegExp`s (and you should be using [`Pattern`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/Pattern-class.html), not `RegExp`, as the type you accept already), and start using just strings or code unit sequences to search for.

Then it will make sense to scan each incoming chunk to the end, and remember whether you have seen a partial delimiter, and how much of one, then you can continue with the next chunk and not need to first combine them in memory to run a `RegExp` over the combination.
It will even allow you to search for the delimiter in incoming *bytes* instead of converting them to a string first, reducing the copy-overhead even more.

It's a little tricky if you allow arbitrary character sequences as line delimiters. For example, using `\r\n\r\n\t` as delimiter, if you have seen `\r\n\r\n` at the end of one chunk, you need to be able to recognize both `\t` and `\r\n\t` at the start of the next.
(You might be able to adapt something like [KMP string search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) for this purpose, or just disallow line delimiters that are not fairly simple).

If you had a `RegExp` implementation based on a state machine, it would be trivial(ish) to keep the state at the end of one chunk and continue matching in the next chunk, but the Dart (JavaScript) `RegExp` is not such an implementation, and it isn't built to do partial matching.
Converting the `RegExp` itself into one which matches prefixes of what the original would match, and detecting which prefix, is not something I'd recommend. Simply because it's [very non-trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015612/convert-a-regular-expression-a-that-accepts-a-set-of-strings-to-one-that-accepts-all-prefixes-of-the-strings-that-a-matches). And that's for `RegExp`s that are actually *regular*, which the Dart ones are not (back-references are non-regular).